# React-router v4 history.push, div vs button

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, react-router-v4, browser-history

I have a react component like this

```
import * as React from 'react';
...
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    onCreate = () => {
        this.props.actions.create();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.onCreate}>Button</button>
                <div onClick={this.onCreate}>Div</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`this.onCreate` is passed into `OtherComponent`, which passes the function down a few more times into another react component where it is eventually called when a div is clicked.

My action creator looks like this:

```
import {history} from '../../../index.tsx';
...
create: () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(new ActionOne());
    dispatch(new ActionTwo());
    history.push('/someurl');
    debugger;
    dispatch(new ActionThree());
}
...
```

History is just this:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
...
export const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Route path="/" component={AppM} />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The problem is different behaviour when `history.push` occurs from the button vs the div.

From the button, when the debugger line is hit, the webpage is already showing `/someurl`, but from the div, `/someurl` is not yet showing, but will eventually appear sometime after `ActionThree` is finished.

I can get consistent behaviour if I wrap `history.push('/someurl');` or `dispatch(new ActionThree());` in a `setTimeout`, but I'd like to understand what is happening here. What could be the cause for the difference in behaviour?